# Centering a Helix along an Arbitrary Vector in 3D

Tags: geometry, vectors, spherical-coordinates

I know that the parametrization of a helix centered along the z-axis is $\vec r(t)=<cos(t),sin(t),t>$. However, is there some way to center the helix along some arbitrary vector $\vec n$? I was thinking maybe I could use spherical coordinates and then $\rho=t\hat n$, but I can't figure out how to solve for $\phi$ and $\theta$. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would find $\mathbf u,\mathbf v$ such that $\mathbf u,\mathbf v$ are unit vectors perpendicular to $\mathbf n$

For any $\mathbf n$ it is pretty easy to find one orthogonal vector.  Then take the cross product to find the other.  Scale them down to unit vectors.

$\mathbf n t + \mathbf u \cos t + \mathbf v \sin t$ would be your helix.

Comment: This is good. Just adding that this gives you a right-handed helix. If you want a left-handed helix, use $-\mathbf{v}$ instead of $\mathbf{v}$. And to adjust the phase of the helix replace $t$ with $t+\phi_0$ to rotate it by the (fixed) angle $\phi_0$ about $\mathbf{n}$.

Comment: Thank you very much! Apparently it's a lot simpler than I anticipated haha